# Não consigo acessar o texto que se encontra dentro de um array de objetos em MongoDB após aplicar forEach

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Não estou conseguindo acessar o meu array de objetos que foram configurados em meu mongoose.Schema usando forEach.

```js
const quizSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        question: String,
        answers : [
            {first: String},
            {second: String},
            {third: String}
        ]
    }
);

const Quiz = mongoose.model('Quiz', quizSchema);
```

Quando faço :

```js
app.get('/nivelamento', (req, res) => {
    Quiz.find((err, allQuizzes) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {                          
            const firstAnswer  = allQuizzes[1].answers[0].first;
            console.log(firstAnswer);

            res.render('nivelamento', {questions: allQuizzes});
        };
    });
});
```

Ok, meu console retorna o que estou querendo. Mas quando eu uso forEach ele me retorna um array com _id mais o objeto. E quando tento acessar apenas o objeto, sem o _id, não consigo.

```js
<section class="nivelamento" id="nivelamento">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="nivelamento-titulo">Test your English!</h2>
           <% questions.forEach((quiz) =>{ %>
                <h4> <%= quiz.question %></h4>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            <%= quiz.answers[0] %>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            <%= quiz.answers[1] %>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            <%= quiz.answers[2] %>
                        </label>
                   </div>              
            <% }); %>                                 
        </div>
    </section>
```

Já tentei : quiz.answers.first (mas diz que 'first' é 'undefined');
Já tentei: quiz.answers[0].first (recebo '[0]' também é 'undefined');

Então, no momento só consigo printar na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me dizer por que não consigo acessar o texto da resposta e por que tenho 3 chekbox criadas sem valores?

Comment: Mas a forma de acessar essa informação deveria ser `quiz.answers[0].first` mesmo, a menos que essa informação ainda esteja serializada em forma de string por alguma razão, nesse caso seria `JSON.parse(quiz.answers[0]).first`. De qualquer modo, poste seu HTML na pergunta, não uma imagem com parte do código recortado.

Comment: Não dá certo fazer JSON.parse(quiz.answers[0]).first.  Também tirei as imagens e coloquei o código.